# The system is running in low-graphics mode on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

After googling for hours and trying different things for hours I need your help:
I updated the system and after a reboot I cannot log into Ubuntu again (unfortunately I don't know which packages got upgraded)...

Anyways after boot the screen shows the well known 

`The system is running in low-graphics mode`

I tried to purge all off the `nvidia-` packages. Tried to reinstall `xserver-xorg-video-*` removed `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` - to no avail

Logfiles:
`Xorg.1.log`

```
[    22.512] 
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
[    22.512] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    22.512] Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-68-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    22.512] Current Operating System: Linux andreas-Lenovo-U530 4.2.0-23-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Sun Dec 27 17:47:31 UTC 2015 x86_64
[    22.512] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-23-generic root=UUID=4d69246f-f0fb-4de4-bf87-fa73813505da ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    22.512] Build Date: 12 November 2015  05:33:29PM
[    22.512] xorg-server 2:1.17.2-1ubuntu9.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    22.512] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[    22.512]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    22.512] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    22.512] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Mon Jan 11 19:28:13 2016
[    22.512] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    22.512] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    22.512] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    22.512] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    22.512] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    22.513] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    22.513] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    22.513] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    22.513] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    22.513] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    22.513]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.513] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    22.513]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.513] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    22.513]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.513] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    built-ins
[    22.513] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    22.513] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    22.513] (II) Loader magic: 0x558ecb115d40
[    22.513] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    22.513]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    22.513]    X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
[    22.513]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[    22.513]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    22.513] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    22.514] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    22.515] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0a16:17aa:3800 rev 11, Mem @ 0xb5000000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00006000/64
[    22.515] (--) PCI: (0:9:0:0) 10de:1290:17aa:3800 rev 161, Mem @ 0xb3000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, 0xb0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00003000/128
[    22.515] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    22.515] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    22.516] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.516]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    22.516]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[    22.516] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    22.516] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    22.516] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 1
[    22.516] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 2
[    22.516] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 3
[    22.516] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 4
[    22.516] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 5
[    22.516] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[    22.516] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    22.516] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    22.516] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    22.516] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.516]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 2.99.917
[    22.516]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.516]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.516] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    22.516] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    22.516] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    22.516] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    22.516] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    22.516] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    22.516] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    22.517] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.517]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.11
[    22.517]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.517]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.517] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    22.517] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    22.517] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.517]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.17.2
[    22.517]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.517]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.517] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    22.517] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    22.517] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.517]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    22.517]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.517]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.517] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    22.517] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    22.517] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.517]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.4
[    22.517]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.517]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.517] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    22.517] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 1
[    22.517] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 2
[    22.517] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 3
[    22.517] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 4
[    22.517] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 5
[    22.517] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[    22.517] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    22.517] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    22.517] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    22.517] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.517]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 2.99.917
[    22.517]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.517]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.517] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[    22.517] (II) Unloading intel
[    22.517] (II) Failed to load module "intel" (already loaded, 21902)
[    22.517] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    22.517] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    22.517] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    22.517] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    22.517] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    22.517] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    22.517] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    22.517] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.517]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.11
[    22.517]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.517]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.517] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    22.517] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    22.517] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 0)
[    22.517] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    22.517] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    22.517] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.517]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.17.2
[    22.517]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.517]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.517] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    22.517] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    22.517] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[    22.517] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    22.518] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    22.518] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.518]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    22.518]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.518]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.518] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    22.518] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    22.518] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[    22.518] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    22.518] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    22.518] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.518]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.4
[    22.518]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.518]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.518] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    22.518] (II) Unloading vesa
[    22.518] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[    22.518] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    22.518] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[    22.518] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[    22.518] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[    22.518] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Thu Aug 28 03:57:48 2014 +0200
[    22.518] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    22.518]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    22.518]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    22.518]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    22.518]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    22.518]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    22.518]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    22.518]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    22.518]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    22.518]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    22.518]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    22.518]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    22.518]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    22.518]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    22.518] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms 
[    22.518] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    22.518] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    22.518] (++) using VT number 7
```

`dmesg` (removed the first bit; there seem to be some errors related to VGA, but I don't know what they mean exactly)

```
[   14.043379] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   14.043380] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.043382] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.043384] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.043388] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   14.044156] hid-multitouch 0003:03EB:8827.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[   14.064682] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input13
[   14.064729] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input14
[   14.064773] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input15
[   14.071295] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC3239: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   14.071300] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   14.071303] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   14.071305] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   14.071307] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[   14.071310] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0x19
[   14.071312] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[   14.073490] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   14.097175] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   14.097423] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[   14.097425] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[   14.097790] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   14.098657] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-15.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.098698] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.110526] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710018002030d00
[   14.129340] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input16
[   14.130343] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input17
[   14.130475] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.30.13.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   14.132565] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[   14.171786] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Lenovo EasyCamera (13d3:5172)
[   14.177542] input: Lenovo EasyCamera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input18
[   14.177714] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   14.177716] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   14.209070] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[   14.209073] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[   14.212818] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless N 7260, REV=0x144
[   14.213012] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.213312] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.261257] kvm: disabled by bios
[   14.274385] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   14.274389] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   14.278311] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   14.280968] Adding 8312828k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8312828k SSFS
[   14.283294] nvidia 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[   14.283541] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20150116 for 0000:09:00.0 on minor 1
[   14.283544] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  352.63  Sat Nov  7 21:25:42 PST 2015
[   14.289255] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   14.289258] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   14.289259] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   14.289261] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.289262] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.289263] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.289264] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.289266] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   14.289267] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   14.289268] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.289269] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.290650] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[   14.322417] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[   14.322421] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[   14.322423] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   14.322425] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[   14.449884] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   14.452751] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   14.644158] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[   14.818834] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   14.818838] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   14.818841] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   14.913512] bbswitch: version 0.7
[   14.913520] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[   14.913527] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:09:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP
[   14.913540] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   14.913623] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[   14.913632] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:09:00.0 is on
[   14.957075] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[   14.976135] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link down
[   14.976177] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[   14.978228] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   14.978321] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.978555] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   15.199219] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   15.199457] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   15.220043] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   15.382707] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   15.527255] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   15.533253] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   15.533286] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   15.533303] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   15.533326] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   15.533342] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   15.533358] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   15.533389] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   15.533405] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   15.545633] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[   16.281783] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   17.387552] [drm:intel_pipe_config_compare [i915]] *ERROR* mismatch in ips_enabled (expected 1, found 0)
[   17.387556] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   17.387572] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 2485 at /build/linux-AxjFAn/linux-4.2.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:12326 check_crtc_state+0x2c5/0x440 [i915]()
[   17.387573] pipe state doesn't match!
[   17.387574] Modules linked in: bbswitch(OE) bnep arc4 intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp nvidia(POE) coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel iwlmvm aesni_intel mac80211 aes_x86_64 uvcvideo lrw gf128mul glue_helper videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core ablk_helper cryptd v4l2_common iwlwifi videodev btusb input_leds serio_raw joydev media btrtl snd_hda_codec_realtek btbcm snd_hda_codec_hdmi btintel snd_hda_codec_generic cfg80211 lpc_ich bluetooth snd_seq_midi hid_multitouch snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_rawmidi snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_seq mei_me snd_pcm shpchp mei snd_seq_device snd_timer snd ideapad_laptop sparse_keymap soundcore soc_button_array mac_hid wmi intel_smartconnect parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 squashfs
[   17.387614]  overlay nls_iso8859_1 dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_generic usbhid hid uas usb_storage i915 psmouse i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper ahci drm r8169 libahci mii video
[   17.387627] CPU: 0 PID: 2485 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P           OE   4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu
[   17.387628] Hardware name: LENOVO 20289/Plum 5A, BIOS 7CCN60WW 07/21/2014
[   17.387630]  0000000000000000 00000000e3e7ff52 ffff8802511677c8 ffffffff817e8c09
[   17.387632]  0000000000000000 ffff880251167820 ffff880251167808 ffffffff8107b3c6
[   17.387635]  ffff880251167848 ffff8802511678b0 ffff880252452800 0000000000000001
[   17.387637] Call Trace:
[   17.387642]  [<ffffffff817e8c09>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
[   17.387646]  [<ffffffff8107b3c6>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
[   17.387649]  [<ffffffff8107b455>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
[   17.387662]  [<ffffffffc018cbc1>] ? intel_pipe_config_compare+0xb31/0xc60 [i915]
[   17.387674]  [<ffffffffc018cfb5>] check_crtc_state+0x2c5/0x440 [i915]
[   17.387690]  [<ffffffffc01a0d6d>] intel_modeset_check_state+0x21d/0x6d0 [i915]
[   17.387703]  [<ffffffffc01a1f27>] intel_crtc_set_config+0x4c7/0x580 [i915]
[   17.387717]  [<ffffffffc0056ee5>] ? drm_mode_create+0x25/0x60 [drm]
[   17.387727]  [<ffffffffc00504c6>] drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x66/0x100 [drm]
[   17.387737]  [<ffffffffc0054b29>] drm_mode_setcrtc+0x3e9/0x500 [drm]
[   17.387744]  [<ffffffffc0045495>] drm_ioctl+0x125/0x610 [drm]
[   17.387752]  [<ffffffffc0054740>] ? drm_mode_setplane+0x1b0/0x1b0 [drm]
[   17.387756]  [<ffffffff812108a5>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x295/0x480
[   17.387759]  [<ffffffff81087f61>] ? __set_task_blocked+0x41/0xa0
[   17.387761]  [<ffffffff81210b09>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[   17.387764]  [<ffffffff8108ab74>] ? SyS_rt_sigprocmask+0x74/0xc0
[   17.387767]  [<ffffffff817ef9f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
[   17.387769] ---[ end trace a2f0f669433a0771 ]---
[   18.896530] [drm:intel_pipe_config_compare [i915]] *ERROR* mismatch in ips_enabled (expected 1, found 0)
[   18.896535] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   18.896553] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 2485 at /build/linux-AxjFAn/linux-4.2.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:12326 check_crtc_state+0x2c5/0x440 [i915]()
[   18.896554] pipe state doesn't match!
[   18.896556] Modules linked in: bbswitch(OE) bnep arc4 intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp nvidia(POE) coretemp kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel iwlmvm aesni_intel mac80211 aes_x86_64 uvcvideo lrw gf128mul glue_helper videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core ablk_helper cryptd v4l2_common iwlwifi videodev btusb input_leds serio_raw joydev media btrtl snd_hda_codec_realtek btbcm snd_hda_codec_hdmi btintel snd_hda_codec_generic cfg80211 lpc_ich bluetooth snd_seq_midi hid_multitouch snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_rawmidi snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_seq mei_me snd_pcm shpchp mei snd_seq_device snd_timer snd ideapad_laptop sparse_keymap soundcore soc_button_array mac_hid wmi intel_smartconnect parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 squashfs
[   18.896596]  overlay nls_iso8859_1 dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_generic usbhid hid uas usb_storage i915 psmouse i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper ahci drm r8169 libahci mii video
[   18.896609] CPU: 0 PID: 2485 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P        W  OE   4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu
[   18.896611] Hardware name: LENOVO 20289/Plum 5A, BIOS 7CCN60WW 07/21/2014
[   18.896612]  0000000000000000 00000000e3e7ff52 ffff8802511677c8 ffffffff817e8c09
[   18.896615]  0000000000000000 ffff880251167820 ffff880251167808 ffffffff8107b3c6
[   18.896617]  ffff880251167848 ffff8802511678b0 ffff880252452800 0000000000000001
[   18.896620] Call Trace:
[   18.896625]  [<ffffffff817e8c09>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
[   18.896630]  [<ffffffff8107b3c6>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
[   18.896633]  [<ffffffff8107b455>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
[   18.896647]  [<ffffffffc018cbc1>] ? intel_pipe_config_compare+0xb31/0xc60 [i915]
[   18.896660]  [<ffffffffc018cfb5>] check_crtc_state+0x2c5/0x440 [i915]
[   18.896676]  [<ffffffffc01a0d6d>] intel_modeset_check_state+0x21d/0x6d0 [i915]
[   18.896690]  [<ffffffffc01a1f27>] intel_crtc_set_config+0x4c7/0x580 [i915]
[   18.896705]  [<ffffffffc0056ee5>] ? drm_mode_create+0x25/0x60 [drm]
[   18.896715]  [<ffffffffc00504c6>] drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x66/0x100 [drm]
[   18.896726]  [<ffffffffc0054b29>] drm_mode_setcrtc+0x3e9/0x500 [drm]
[   18.896733]  [<ffffffffc0045495>] drm_ioctl+0x125/0x610 [drm]
[   18.896742]  [<ffffffffc0054740>] ? drm_mode_setplane+0x1b0/0x1b0 [drm]
[   18.896746]  [<ffffffff812108a5>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x295/0x480
[   18.896749]  [<ffffffff81087f61>] ? __set_task_blocked+0x41/0xa0
[   18.896752]  [<ffffffff81210b09>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[   18.896755]  [<ffffffff8108ab74>] ? SyS_rt_sigprocmask+0x74/0xc0
[   18.896758]  [<ffffffff817ef9f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
[   18.896760] ---[ end trace a2f0f669433a0772 ]---
[   20.870324] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.870333] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.870338] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   80.482125] wlp2s0: authenticate with 64:7c:34:af:96:22
[   80.485412] wlp2s0: send auth to 64:7c:34:af:96:22 (try 1/3)
[   80.511443] wlp2s0: authenticated
[   80.514283] wlp2s0: associate with 64:7c:34:af:96:22 (try 1/3)
[   80.518614] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 64:7c:34:af:96:22 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[   80.519847] wlp2s0: associated
[   80.519890] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[   80.524680] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: AT
[   80.524684] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
[   80.524686] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   80.524689] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   80.524692] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   80.524694] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   80.524697] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
[   80.524699] cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[  291.363319] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

`lshw -c video`

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:b5000000-b53fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:6000(size=64)
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK208M [GeForce GT 730M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:52 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```